# Decompose a Real symmetric matrix into only 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

- For a real symmetric matrix $A\in\mathbb{S}^n$, we can decompose it into
  $A=U\Lambda U^{T}$
  by Spectral Theorem.
- In Matlab, using the command $[L,S,R] = svd(A)$, we obtain $LS R^{T}$ (here, $L$ stands for the $\textbf{L}$eft matrix, and $R$ stands for the $\textbf{R}$ight matrix). It is normally shown that $L\neq R$. This means that $U$ and $L$ are not the same matrix.
- My question is here: $\textbf{How to get $U$ from $L$ and $R$ theoretically?}$ Can anyone help me, please?

Similar topics:

[Spectral Theorem][1]: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/thm_sed.html

[2] [eigendecomposition of symmetric matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66510/eigendecomposition-of-symmetric-matrix)

[3] [Decompose a real symmetric matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875729/decompose-a-real-symmetric-matrix)

Comment: So, $U$ is a matrix whose columns are (normalized) eigenvectors of $A$. Do you know a similar description of $L$ and of $R$?

Comment: Also, while usually $L\ne R$, is that still true in your special case, where $A$ is real symmetric?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: 1) $UU^{T}=U^{T}U=I$ and $U$ contains eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Yes, but what about $L$ and $R$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: 2) $A$ is still real symmetric, but I see that in the formulation $A=LSR^{T}$, $S\neq\Lambda$ and $S$ is just a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: $L$ and $R$ are also unitary matrices.

Comment: $S$ is not *just* a diagonal matrix. Its diagonal entries are the "singular values" of $A$. These are the eigenvalues of $AA^t$. But when $A$ is symmetric....